# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code[How to solve?]

Tags: python, xcode, kivy

Build Log

```
sent 2291848470 bytes  received 1463928 bytes  8509507.97 bytes/sec
total size is 10369715881  speedup is 4.52
rsync warning: some files vanished before they could be transferred (code 24) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/810eba08-405a-11ed-86e9-6af958a02716/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I have try different ways to solve it but it seems doesn't work for me. For example,

**Solution 1**

1. Open the Xcode project folder in your Terminal app.
2. Enter and execute the following command: pod deintegrate
3. Execute this command: pod install
4. Re-open Xcode > go to Product > Clean Build Folder.
5. Run your app again.

**Solution #2**

1. Head over to Keychain Access.
2. Select Lock & unlock again from the login option.
3. Open Xcode > Clean Xcode Project > Run your build again.

Do anyone have other solution to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution.

I think this is because the "build" and "dist" directories that are created in the current working directory by the "toolchain build" process get recursively included in the project created by "toolchain create", which in turn confuses rsync when it's copying files around.
So, for me, the key was to do the "toolchain build" outside my application source directory tree.

This solved it: https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios/issues/513